# Why would a SSD reset itself every cold boot?

Tags: ssd

First, some system information:

Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-X58A-UD3R
SSD's (x2): Corsair CSSD-F160GBP2
Windows 7 Pro
Totally new system, parts arrived on Friday.

Initially I wanted to setup the two SSD's in RAID1, but this problem initially manifested itself even at this early stage; one drive would keep resetting itself to be outside the VD. At the time I put it down to busted drivers in Windows and finally gave up, installing Windows on two separate disks. Now I am fairly sure something bigger is going on.

Every time I cold boot my new computer the second drive (thankfully not my boot disk!) shows up in Windows as uninitialized, all I can do is reformat it and try again. This happens consistently on cold boots, though warm boots/restarts seem to be fine.

I'm about to try some other SATA ports on my motherboard, hopefully that is all it is. If anyone else has some ideas, I'd be very happy to hear them, I'm just about out of them. Did I buy a bung drive?

**EDIT:** Different SATA ports for both drives, same result. Cold boot == death. Thoughts please, anyone?

Comment: Was it just BIOS boot sector protection blocking your partition table from being saved?

Comment: @rakslice: I got the drive RMA'd, and the new drive has been working fine for the last year and a bit with no changes to the BIOS, so I have to assume not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could just be a faulty drive.

Comment: Seems weird that it works perfectly up till a reboot though... Reading the Corsair forums there seems to be some issues with Gigabyte motherboards, so I'm going down that track at the moment... If so, this is the second of two Gigabyte motherboards I've had issues with.